# How to get unread messages from server webmail in php

Tags: php, imap, pop3, webmail

I'm integrating webmail inbox access process. See my code is below. It does not get unread message it will bring all messages. How can i get only unread messages Kindly advice me.

```
$emails = imap_search($openmail, 'UNSEEN');
```

see above line it does not working.

```
$authhost="{example.com:110/pop3}INBOX";
$username="xxx@example.com";
$password="wxwxwxw";   

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($authhost,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Mail Server: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN');
// echo count($emails);exit;

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';
    /* put the newest emails on top */
    // rsort($emails);
    /* for every email... */
    // $count = 1;

    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $head = imap_header($inbox, $email_number);     
        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

        /*  echo "<pre>";
        print_r($overview);exit;  */

        $obj_thang = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $email_number);
        // print_r($overview);exit;
        $message = imap_body($inbox,$email_number,2);       


        /* output the email header information */       
        $output.= $obj_thang->subject;      
        //$output.= $obj_thang->fromaddress."<br/>";        
        $output.= $obj_thang->reply_toaddress."<br/>";      
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting to POP3, not IMAP. Pop3 does not support server side search, nor a concept of unseen vs seen messages.